# Can't write to a spawned child_process's stdin on Windows

Tags: node.js

The below code works fine on linux, but breaks on Windows 7

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var sass    = spawn('sass');

sass.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});

sass.stdin.write('.asdfsadf\n  color: red', function () {
  sass.stdin.end()
});
```

The error I get is

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:637:19)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:615:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Projects\scaffold-angular\test.js:18:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I've tried this with `slimrb` as well, same 'socket is closed' error.

The commands all work find when I manually enter it on the console (tried both MINGW32 and normal windows commandline).

```
$ sass
.asdfsadf
  color: red
^Z
.asdfsadf {
  color: red; }
```

My node is `v0.10.28`
edit: updated to `v0.10.29`, same issue :(

Comment: gulp-ruby-sass uses the [`win-spawn`](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/win-spawn) module. https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/blob/b3611d5cef044a6b4ccca820071f02cd00f8c19a/index.js#L6

Comment: yup that worked! kind of sucks though..can't use some gulp packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`cross-spawn` package](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) as a drop-in replacement for `child_process.spawn`.

Comment: The github repo for win-spawn says to use a new module called cross spawn now: https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn