# uglify crashing after running child_process.execFile

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, gruntjs, child-process

**EDIT 2**

I "solved" the problem, but I don't want to post it as an answer b/c it doesn't explain what actually happened.  In the code for the .NET `resourceReader.exe` I use

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

to output the internationalized resources to `stdout` in unicode.  If I reset the encoding at the end of my program with

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
```

then I don't get any errors in Node.  If I don't reset it, I get the error described in the original question.  It seems that .NET is somehow messing up some of the output encoding settings on the `cmd.exe` and causing the subsequent node run to fail!

**EDIT**

I narrowed down the error to being caused by `resourceReader.exe`.  It's  a.NET program which reads some resource streams out of the .NET assembly and prints them to the stdout using `Console.WriteLine`.  I added `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` to `resourceReader.exe` because some of the resources are in non ASCII letters and that's whats causing the crash in grunt!

If I take that line out, the task doesn't crash, but the resources show up in non printable ASCII characters!  Also, the crash only happens if I actually print non-ASCII to sdtout.  If I don't print them, it doesn't error.

**ORIGINAL**

I added a step to my Gruntfile which uses `child_process.execFile` to run an read some data from an external program and uses it in the build.  Now whenever I run my build, it runs fine the first time, but crashes the second time!

Here's the output from the crash (this is during the uglify task):

```
File build/Scripts/NDB.contacts.min.js created: 16.85 kBevents.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: This socket is closed.
  at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:656:19)
  at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:709:8)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
  at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
  at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
  at Log._write (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\index.js:161:26)
  at Log.wrapper [as _write] (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
  at Log._writeln (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\index.js:166:8)
  at Log.wrapper [as _writeln] (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
  at Log.writeln (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\index.js:177:8)
  at Log.wrapper (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
  at writeln (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\fail.js:30:13)
  at Object.fail.fatal (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\fail.js:46:3)
  at process.uncaughtHandler (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:121:10)
  at process.emit (events.js:129:20)
  at process._fatalException (node.js:236:26)
  at Task.runTaskFn (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:250:7)
  at Task.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:293:12)
  at C:\...\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:220:11
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Here's the code for the task which uses child_process.

```
    function readAllCultures() {
        var readDeferred = q.defer();

        childProc.execFile("../tools/resourceReader.exe", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err);

            var cultures = JSON.parse(stdout);
            readDeferred.resolve(cultures);
        });

        return readDeferred.promise;
    }
```

Here's some things I discovered debugging that might be helpful

1. If I redirect the output of grunt (using either `> filename` or `| process`) it runs fine
2. When I redirect output, *I never see the message from uglify that it created the main output* only that it created the source map.
3. If I close and reopen my command prompt (`cmd.exe`) it works fine
4. I added a listener to the `exit` and `close` events of the child process using `rdr.on("close", function() { console.log("close"); });` and the same for exit.  Both events fire as expected in the first run.
5. Using Process Explorer, I can see `node.exe` open under the command prompt and close again when my command finishes running.  There are no processes visibly "left open" under the command prompt.

Comment: I think your program is still running in background after your first Grunt call, use htop to confirm.

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD I'm on Windows.  I don't see it running in process manager.

Comment: Well sorry I have no further idea :/
I feel like something is not terminated well (like an open pipe, a socket...) that block the new instance to run.
Good luck

Comment: BTW you should use rather `return readDeferred.reject()` than throwing from callback handler.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: The fact that redirects affect this makes sense when you take a look at what grunt-legacy-log is doing. If you take a look here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-legacy-log/blob/master/index.js#L161 (as found in the stacktrace) the "socket" trying to be written seems to be stdout

Comment: Seeing as I didn't really do anything, not submitting this as an answer, but pretty sure your problem has something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356803/cant-write-to-a-spawned-child-processs-stdin-on-windows

Comment: @photoionized I switched to cross-spawn to see if it would help.  I still get the exact same error on second run!

Comment: @photoionized See my update.  Seems to be the .NET program is somehow "breaking" the environment.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the stack trace is ultimately showing a `socket.write` error is interesting. Nothing in the code you've provided suggests you are trying to write to a socket.

If we follow the stack down, we can see that it's actually grunt that is trying to write to a socket, as it's attempting to log an uncaught exception.

So, first your grunt task throws a currently unknown error, and then grunt itself errors because it can't tell you about it.

I would first try and log the error that occurs in your child process. Currently if there is an error present, you simply `throw` it without finding out what it is. It's likely that this is what grunt is trying and failing to log.

Replace

`if (err) throw new Error(err);`

With

`if (err) console.error(err);`

This will hopefully avoid the `socket.write` problem and give you specific information about what error is happening on the child process. What do you see?

Second, I would try using `child_process.exec` instead of `child_process.execFile`. This will spawn a shell and run `resourceReader.exe` inside of it (instead of running it directly). This might help avoid any problems you are encountering with the command still running/failing in the background, which could be the cause of the `socket.write` error.

Comment: My read culture task runs *after* the uglify task.  I tried your suggestion and it did not make any change to the output.